# How to create a page using a form? php/html

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

Similar to how you create a post in wordpress or even ask a question on this very website.

I want to know how to create a page by just filling out a form?

Here's what I know:

-I know how to make an html form

-I know how to place data in a database and take it out

-I know some php

What I don't know is how to to tie all of these things together. Please be as specific as possible and if you know of a tutorial on how to do this or you have the time to make a small example I would be very very grateful.

Thank you in advance for your time :-)

EDIT: To provide more details

I want to send data from a form (even a few text inputs would be enough) and for them to be placed in a page where I can display them.

And also that page should have an unique identifier so it gets stored similar to the questions on stack overflow where there is www.stackoverflow.com/posts/'identifiernumber'
And I would always to go back to that information provided I access the link which I assumed will be stored in the database.

Comment: Your question is vague enough that it might be downvoted. Do you want to create a post or an entire page from this HTML form?

Comment: `<?php echo $_GET['name'];?> <form><input name="name" /><input type="submit" /></form>`

Comment: Here you go http://bit.ly/VN8J4X

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create static html page using html form input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315096/create-static-html-page-using-html-form-input)

Comment: I'm trying to add as many specifics as possible. Please let me know if there are any more I can add. I will edit my question to provide you an answer in a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wordpress` uses `wysiwyg` this is used to convert normal text into html code you can find jquery plugins for it.After user has entered the content of the page and hits submit. Wordpress directly stores the content in the database in `HTML FORMAT` . Now all it does is `echo` out the content stored in the database.

Now for the identifier , it should point out to the primary key of the database row where the content is stored. `Wordpress` stores a unique url as the identifier like the questions you asked is  **How to create a page using a form? php/html** it will store it as **how-to-create-a-page-using-a-form-php-html** . This is then put in the `href` attribute of `<a>` tag , on click of this unique identifier it `echo` out the content of that row.

All you have to do now is make a form and textarea , apply the `wysiwyg` plugin on the textarea . Then onsubmit store the data in the database and also creating a unique identifier for it.

**You question now is how to pass the identifier in the `URL`?**

First you must know how to pass a variable in the `URL` and then capture it in the required place eg : `www.yourwebsite.com?identifier=something` and to make this a link on you website

```
<a href="www.yourwebsite.com?identifier=something">Something</a>
```

Once you have mastered this you can then study a concept called `MOD REWRITE` and in layman term for this is called **clean URL** or **SEO URL** . There are many blogs and methods of achieving this goal. You can google `MOD REWRITE` and `SEO URL`.

Comment: Could you go more onto detail about the identifier part? It's the only thing I'm having a hard time figuring out the rest seem very easy to do.

Comment: @Bob what about the identifier? Storing? Creating? or ?

Comment: I know how to create one, and store it, what I don't know is how do I make it become a URL like www.website.com/something/identifier-goes-here

Comment: @Bob i hope i have answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

Create your website theme

on first page create form like you want

concept is like registration form and second page is edit profile

now what you stored in database from registration form

now echo in your edit profile form 
for example username in database can be viewed in edit profile form

```
    select * FROM registrationtable WHERE userid='$userid'
```

then store values in variables like for example

```
while ($query = mysql_fetch_array($request))
{
$username = $query['username'];

}


<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/>
```

p.s dont use mysql better options are mysqli and PDO